# Casting Html Controls (.NET 2.0)

Tags: controls, .net-2.0, boxing, unboxing

I have used the below code to cast controls:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(count);

div = new HtmlGenericControl();

div.Controls.Add((HtmlGenericControl)result[j]["fly"]);
div.Controls.Add((HtmlImage)result[j]["img"]);
div.Controls.Add((HtmlGenericControl)result[j]["bar"]);
div.Controls.Add((HtmlGenericControl)result[j]["meter"]);
div.Controls.Add((HtmlGenericControl)result[j]["block"]);

this.display.Controls.Add(div);
```

The problem is that, even though it compiles it doesn't work - throws an HttpException. 
I don't think I am casting the control correctly?

I AM USING Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a more elaborate code example? And with a debugger verify that 'result[j]["xxx"] are in fact HtmlGenericControls?